# How do I select a specific double-nested element inside a div without jquery?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a script called swipeview to put multiple instances of a gallery on a page. It generates the structure like this:

```
<div id="slider-1">
    <div id="swipeview-slider">
        <div id="swipeview-masterpage">
            <img src="images/01.jpg" id="one"/>
        </div>
        <div id="swipeview-masterpage" class="swipeview-active">
            <img src="images/02.jpg" id="two"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="slider-2">
    <div id="swipeview-slider">
        <div id="swipeview-masterpage">
            <img src="images/01.jpg" id="one"/>
        </div>
        <div id="swipeview-masterpage" class="swipeview-active">
            <img src="images/02.jpg" id="two"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The only thing that is unique to each image is the top-level div ID (slider-1, slider-2).

Without using jQuery, how can I get the ID of each separate image within the 'swipeview-active' class?

With jQuery I would select them with something along these lines:

```
$('#slider-1 > .swipeview-slider > .swipeview-masterpage .swipeview-active > img ').attr('id');
```

How can I do achieve this in regular js?

Comment: You have got duplicate IDs, and IDs beginning with numbers, both of which are *invalid*.

Comment: I know semantically its invalid, but I want to use them in an iOS safari page, so it will work.

Comment: @reekogi: Regardless of where you use it, you should fix it.  Having multiple IDs will make your JavaScript more complicated and harder to debug.

Comment: @reekogi Your current selector is also wrong, even after replacing `id` with `class`. The space between `.swipe-masterpage` and `.swipteview-active` has to be removed, because these are the class names of the same element. In selectors (jQuery, CSS), a space separates descendants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: **IDs must not start with a digit**.
The `dot`-selector selects elements by *class name*. Use `class=..` instead of `id=...`.

Corrected code, using [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) (**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rGAkm/3/**).

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('#slider-1 > .swipeview-slider > .swipeview-masterpage .swipeview-active > img[id]');
var len = images.length;
var output = document.getElementById('output');
for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
    var image = images[i];
    output.appendChild(image);
}
```

Replace `#slider-1` with `[id^="slider-"]` if you want to select all images in this structure, which is a child of `id="slider-1"`, `id="slider-2"`, ...

Comment: MDN is currently experiencing technical problems. You can find the cached version of the documentation [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:kn5_uxTVAkcJ:https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk).

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I tried getting the ID with 
var images = document.querySelectorAll('#slider-1 .swipe-active img[id]');
but to no avail...

Comment: Cheers for the edit, but the array and the images var are blank when I run it -> http://jsfiddle.net/rGAkm/1/

Comment: @reekogi Your code was terribly wrong: Use `class=...` to select elements elements using that selector.

Comment: @reekogi: Change `swipeview-masterpage` and `swipeview-slider` from IDs to classes in your HTML.

Comment: Additional note to @Rocket comment: Since you've already defined another class attribute, add the contents of the `id` attribute to the `class` attribute, separated by a white-space character.

Comment: Yeah apologies, I posted on the way out of the office without checking it over. Just checked the jsfiddle amends you made and it's working. Many thanks, appreciate the effort!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but it works. I replaced the `img` tags with `span` tags for demonstration. I also gave the last 2 span tags a different `id`, and added one extra, to show it working on both root slider divs for any number of spans (images). Hope it helps.
http://jsfiddle.net/vNqhd/3/

html:

```
<div id="slider-1">
    <div id="swipeview-slider">
        <div id="swipeview-masterpage">
            <span id="one">img1</span>
        </div>
        <div id="swipeview-masterpage" class="swipeview-active">
            <span id="two">img2</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="slider-2">
    <div id="swipeview-slider">
        <div id="swipeview-masterpage">
            <span id="three">img3</span>
        </div>
        <div id="swipeview-masterpage" class="swipeview-active">
            <span id="four">img4</span>
        </div>
        <div id="swipeview-masterpage" class="swipeview-active">
            <span id="five">img5</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="myfunc('slider-1');">button</button>
<button onclick="myfunc('slider-2');">button</button>
<div id="msg"></div>
```

js:

```
function myfunc(divID){
    var myVar = document.getElementById(divID);
    var imgIDs = [];
    var counter = 0;
    var str = "";

    //walk the DOM from a root div and look for img/span tags
    //and store their IDs
    while(true){
        if(myVar === undefined){ break; }
        if(myVar.getElementsByTagName('div').length > 0){
            myVar = myVar.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
            continue;
        } else if(myVar.getElementsByTagName('span').length > 0){
            imgIDs.push(myVar.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].id);
            counter++;
            myVar = myVar.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[counter];
        } else { break; }
    }
    //display results
    for(var i = 0; i < imgIDs.length; i++){
        str += imgIDs[i] + "<br/>";
    }
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = str;
}
```